# Making fitdist plots with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, distribution, fitdistrplus

I fitted the normal distribution with `fitdist` function from `fitdistrplus` package. Using `denscomp`, `qqcomp`, `cdfcomp` and `ppcomp` we can plot `histogram against fitted density functions`, `theoretical quantiles against empirical ones`, `the empirical cumulative distribution against fitted distribution functions`, and `theoretical probabilities against empirical ones` respectively as given below.

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- rnorm(n=10, mean = 0, sd =1)
library(fitdistrplus)
fm1 <-fitdist(data = df, distr = "norm")
summary(fm1)

denscomp(ft = fm1, legendtext = "Normal")
```

[image]

```
qqcomp(ft = fm1, legendtext = "Normal")
```

[image]

```
cdfcomp(ft = fm1, legendtext = "Normal")
```

[image]

```
ppcomp(ft = fm1, legendtext = "Normal")
```

[image]

I'm keenly interested to make these `fitdist` plots with `ggplot2`. MWE is below:

```
qplot(df, geom = 'blank') +
  geom_line(aes(y = ..density.., colour = 'Empirical'), stat = 'density') +  
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), fill = 'gray90', colour = 'gray40') +
  geom_line(stat = 'function', fun = dnorm, 
            args = as.list(fm1$estimate), aes(colour = 'Normal')) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Density', values = c('red', 'blue'))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(sample = df)) + stat_qq(dist = "norm", dparam = fm1$estimate)
```

How can I start making these `fitdist` plots with `ggplot2`?

Comment: If this hadn't a bounty attached I would vote to close as too broad. Each graph should be a different question (although you might not need to ask for each graph if you had an answer for one or two of them).

Answer (score 4):

you could use something like that:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dataset, aes(x=variable)) +
geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),binwidth=.5, colour="black", fill="white") +
stat_function(fun=dnorm, args=list(mean=mean(z), sd=sd(z)), aes(colour =
"gaussian", linetype = "gaussian")) + 
stat_function(fun=dfun, aes(colour = "laplace", linetype = "laplace")) + 
scale_colour_manual('',values=c("gaussian"="red", "laplace"="blue"))+
scale_linetype_manual('',values=c("gaussian"=1,"laplace"=1))
```

you just need to define `dfun` before running the graphic. In this example, it's a Laplace distribution but you can pick any you want and add some more `stat_function` if you want.